# driver.get(url) does not work after some process

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

After I login a website, I can't navigate. And program does not throw an error. I suspect from switching the frame but could not manage to solve the problem.

```
            RedditBot.driver.get(self.targetUrl) #working
            
            RedditBot.driver.get("https://www.reddit.com/")
            
            login=RedditBot.driver.find_element_by_link_text("Log In")
            login.click()

            RedditBot.driver.switch_to_frame(RedditBot.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe'))
            username_in = RedditBot.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='loginUsername']")
            self.typing(username_in, "username")

            pass_in = RedditBot.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='loginPassword']")
            self.typing(pass_in, "pass")

            pass_in.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            RedditBot.driver.switch_to_default_content()
            
            RedditBot.driver.get(self.targetUrl) #not working
```

Comment: Is this the end of the program? if it is the driver might get closed by Python right after executing the last command, so you don't have enough time to see it in the UI. Add another line and put a breakpoint on it.

Comment: @Guy thank for advice, actually I deleted delay codes for readibility. But finally, I figured the problem out. It is reddit itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the below code with explicit wait to print the current URL :

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.reddit.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
print(driver.current_url)
login = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href^='https://www.reddit.com/login/?']")))
login.click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src*='login']")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "loginUsername"))).send_keys("your user name")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "loginPassword"))).send_keys("your password")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class^='AnimatedForm__submitButton']"))).click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "header-search-bar"))).send_keys("Python" + Keys.RETURN)
sleep(5)
print(driver.current_url)
```

**O/P :**

```
https://www.reddit.com/
https://www.reddit.com/search/?q=Python

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You need to use the above code first, and check the output before saying it is not addressing, what is the desired outcome ? did it work ? if no then was there any issue ?

Comment: you have mentioned this in your question `After I login a website, I can't navigate. `, that is the reason once logged in I am searching for something and then code is navigating there. I still do not understand the answer posted by you.

Comment: Im sorry, my bad. You are right. Thanks for alternative solution.

Comment: yeah, I tried first in my local and when it worked I posted that as an answer. it should work for you too.